# Add conditional to second left join

Tags: sql-server

Please take a look at the following query:

```
SELECT distinct a.*, coalesce (r.email,r2.email) as 'sign_in_email'
into #adobe_prep
FROM dbo.adobe 
left join 
dbo.registration r ON (a.user_id = r.up_user_id)
left join 
dbo.registration r2 ON (a.user_id = r2.entity_id)
```

I am basically trying to match a.user_id with r.up_user_id and if there is no match with up_user_id, then match entity_id.
However, there is no conditional on this statement so I get duplicates because sometimes a.user_id = r.up_user_id but also a.user_id = r2.entity_id (just for a different value).
Can you help with adding a conditional that the second left join should only occur if a.user_id <> r.up_user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you wrote the answer yourself! Try to add the condition that you wrote in words:

> ```
> and a.user_id <> r.up_user_id
> ```

Like this:

```
select distinct a.*, coalesce (r.email,r2.email) as 'sign_in_email'
into #adobe_prep
from dbo.adobe 
          left join dbo.registration r ON (a.user_id = r.up_user_id)
          left join dbo.registration r2 ON (a.user_id = r2.entity_id and a.user_id <> r.up_user_id)
```